# Resolve circular dependency for Mutually recursive components referencing each other by @ContentChild / @ContentChildren

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two very simple components, which lie in two different files. A **MenuItem** can contain a **MenuGroup**, which is a list of more **MenuItem**s. If a MenuItem does not contain a MenuGroup, it will be an endpoint item.

This will help me building a navigation menu arbitrarily nested, like this one:

*`// template of some navigation menu component`*

```
...
<app-menu-group>

  <app-menu-item title="Europe">
    <app-menu-group>
      <app-menu-item title="United Kingdom"></app-menu-item>
      <app-menu-item title="Germany"></app-menu-item>
    </app-menu-group>
  </app-menu-item>

  <app-menu-item title="America">
  </app-menu-item>

</app-menu-group>
```

The problem arises when you take a look at my two different files. They import into each other, causing the compiler to fail because of a **Circular dependency detected**.

*`// menu-item.component.ts`*

```
import { ... } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuGroupComponent } from './menu-group.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu-item',
  template: ``,
  styles: [``]
})
export class MenuItemComponent {

  @ContentChild(forwardRef(() => MenuGroupComponent)) menuGroup?: MenuGroupComponent;

  @Input() title: string;

}
```

*`menu-group.component.ts`*

```
import { ... } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuItemComponent } from './menu-item.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu-group',
  template: ``,
  styles: [``]
})
export class MenuGroupComponent {

  @ContentChildren(forwardRef(() => MenuItemComponent)) menuItems: QueryList<MenuItemComponent>;

}
```

In theory, Angular should be already resolving the loop, thanks to the *`forwardRef`* that lets me reference the yet-undefined class for both my components. The problem is that Typescript compiler gets angry anyway.

The weirdest thing is that this *perfectly* works on StackBlitz (which I used to develop my prototype), while it fails with AngularCLI compiler.

---> [This is the StackBlitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ccz6jr) <---

Extra interesting bit:

Putting the classes in the same file, solves the compilation problem, but causes a runtime error as like *`forwardRef`* were not working.